# django restframework token causes ImportError

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I tried using django rest framework Token package. after I ran migration then I implemented the get or create method but ran into an error so I decided to run migrations again then i got an error saying `ImportError: No module named authtokencashondelivery`
. I have an application in my project named cash on delivery but I dont know the problem now. If I comment out the rest_framework.token in my settings , everything works fine but I still want to work with it

Comment: Looks like you missed comma after `'rest_framework.authtoken'` line inside `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

Comment: oh. thanks . very grateful

Comment: @neverwalkaloner I suggest you make an answer

Comment: OK, I've posted a little bit more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases the reason of such kind of error is missing comma in `INSTALLED_APPS` setting. You need to check `INSTALLED_APPS` and make it like this:

```
'rest_framework.authtoken',
'cashondelivery'
```

Instead of:

```
'rest_framework.authtoken'
'cashondelivery'
```